# How to filter your admin grid collection based on certain condition in Ui component xml file

Tags: magento2, collection, grid

I want to filter my Grid based on condition that only active entries should be visible on the grid and not all entries from the table

I am using ui component to create grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I’m going to share the custom code which you can implement to UI component grid collection in Magento 2.

Paste the below code in UI component grid xml

```
<dataSource name="test_comments_listing_data_source">
<argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider</argument>
    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">test_comments_listing_data_source</argument>
    <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
    <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="status" xsi:type="string">*</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</argument>
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Inside the argument tag, you can see an item tag with name

> filter_url_params

which is responsible to filter collection.
In order to make it work, set parameter name inside name attribute of item tag through which you require to filter.

Below code displays the example of filter by status on a collection, here you need to pass the is_active value through URL.

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
        <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="is_active" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Hope this will help you
Thanks

Comment: can you please share you full code where I need to add this file with location and di.xml